# How do for of loops handle streams which aren't iterable in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, iterable

In node we can create a read stream for a file with `createReadStream` and then based on that stream we use `readline.createInterface` to get a new stream that emits data line by line.

```
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(inputFilePath);
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fileStream,
  crlfDelay: Infinity
});

for await (const line of rl) {
  // do something
}
```

I have two related questions:

- As I understood, the `for(x of y)` syntax works with iterables. However streams are not iterable, so how does this work?
- I want to ignore the first line emitted on `rl`. There is no `next()` function on `rl` because its not an iterable. So if I want to skip the first line is the way to do this by keeping track of whether we already received a line before then use an if statement inside of the `for of` loop and ignore the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understood, the for(x of y) syntax works with iterables. However streams are not iterable, so how does this work?

`for-of` does indeed require an iterable, but that code is using `for-await-of`, which requires an **`async`** iterable, not an iterable. Those are two different (though closely related) things. :-) Readable streams [are `async` iterable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_symbol_asynciterator) and so you can use `for-await-of` on them. Note that something that's `async` iterable may not be iterable (I suspect often they aren't, since they can't provide their results synchronously).

> I want to ignore the first line emitted on `rl`.

There are a couple of ways to do that:

1. Use a flag
2. Get the `async` iterator directly and call `next`

Using a flag:

```
let first = true;
for await (const line of rl) {
    if (first) {
        first = false;
        continue;
    }
    // do something
}
```

Using the `async` iterator directly:

```
let it = rl[Symbol.asyncIterator](); // Get the async iterator
await it.next();                     // Skip the first result -- note `await`
for await (const line of it) {       // Works in most cases because the async
   /* Note `it` not `rl` ^^ */       // *iterator* is also an async *iterable*
                                     // (and that's true of the one you get
                                     // from `readline`)
    // do something
}
```

It's common for an iterator / `async` iterator to implement `Symbol.iterator` / `Symbol.asyncIterator` by doing `return this`, which makes the iterator *iterable* so they can be used with `for-of` and `for-await-of` respectively.

Comment: FWIW, I go into iterables and `async` iterables in detail in Chapters 6 and 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.